# Access new window elements through selenium RC

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium. This is my first attempt. And I want to access the Elements in the new window through Selenium RC. I have a page with a hyper link clicking on it will open new page. I want to enter username and password elements in the new window. Html Code is

Employee Login

and the new page elements are "emailAddress" and "password" for login.

My selenium code is

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    RemoteControlConfiguration rc=new RemoteControlConfiguration();
    rc.setPort(2343);
    SeleniumServer se= new SeleniumServer(rc);
    Selenium sel=new DefaultSelenium("localhost",2343,"*firefox","http://neo.local/");
    se.start();
    sel.start();
    sel.open("/");
    sel.windowMaximize();
    //sel.wait(1000);
    sel.click("empLogin");
    //sel.wait(2000);       
    //sel.openWindow("http://myneo.neo.local/user/login", "NewNeo");
    //sel.waitForPopUp("NewNeo", "1000");
    //sel.selectWindow("id=NewNeo");
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    sel.type("emailAddress", "kiranxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");
    sel.type("password", "xxxxxxxx");

}
```

First I tried with normal approach, where it failed to identify the elements. Then  I tried with open window and selectWindow options, where it through errors like

```
"Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Window locator not recognized: id
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.selectWindow(DefaultSelenium.java:377)
at Demo.main(Demo.java:24)"
```

Some one told me that it is not possible with Selenium RC. It can achieved through Selenium Webdriver only. Is it true?

Please Help,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thank you Nilesh and sircapsalot. I have a Anchor tag with id as "empLogin". <a href="http://http://myneo.neo.local/user/login" >Employee Login</a>. I googled for the specific problem and I found that it is possible with WebDriver only. Anyway thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selenium RC` is not maintained anymore, I would recommend you to use `WebDriver` instead. `Selenium RC` is a Javascript application where as WebDriver uses browsers Native API. Therefore browser interactions using WebDriver are close to what the real user does. Also WebDriver's API is more intuitive and easy to use in my opinion. I don't see HTML in your question, but you could do start with something like this,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("empLogin"));
login.click();
```

Comment: Yes Nilesh, I Have Tried so many ways. But none worked out. So I have shifter to Selenium WebDriver. @sircapsalot: Thank you very much for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I will say, do as @nilesh stated.  Use Selenium WebDriver.

#### Answer to your specific problem though:

You are failing at this line because you are not specifying a selector strategy.

```
sel.click("empLogin");
```

If the `id` attribute is `empLogin` then do

```
sel.click("id=empLogin");
```

There are other selector strategies you can use:

```
css=
id=
xpath=
link=
etc...
```

You can see the full list [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html).

You will also fail here due to the same issue:

```
sel.type("emailAddress", "kiranxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");
sel.type("password", "xxxxxxxx");
```

Put a selector strategy prefix before those fields.

```
sel.type("name=emailAddress", "kiranxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");
sel.type("name=password", "xxxxxxxx");
```